# Multiple ResultSets

Tags: sql, jsp

I have a university assignment, and I've been asked to display a list of plants from an access database and then also include a search function to filter out these results.

I have the list of plants displayed easy enough. However, I can't get the search to work, so I tried with just another SQL query, and I came up with this error. I have done some reading and searching and I can't seem to find the answer to my question.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is closed

Here is my code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:PlantsDB", "", "");
 Statement st = cn.createStatement();
 ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Plant;");
 String html = "";
 String id;
 while (r.next()) {
  id = Integer.toString(r.getInt("PlantID"));
  html += "<a href='Plant" + id + ".jsp" + "'>";
  html += r.getString("EnglishName") + "-" + r.getString("ScientificName")
  + "<a><br>";
}
r.close();
cn.close();

if (request.getParameter("sBtn") != null) {
 Connection sn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:PlantsDB", "", "");
 //String search = request.getParameter(sQuery);
 //request.getSession().setAttribute("search",search);
 Statement sq = sn.createStatement();
 ResultSet sqr = sq.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Plant WHERE EnglishName LIKE
 '%" + "Co" + "%'");
while (sqr.next()) {
id = Integer.toString(r.getInt("PlantID"));
html += "<a href='Plant" + id + ".jsp" + "'>";
html += r.getString("EnglishName") + "-" + r.getString("ScientificName")
 + "<a><br>";
}
sn.close();
}

%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body bgcolor="#A8A8A8">
<%=html%>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" id="search" name="sQuery">
<input type="submit" id="sBtn" name="sBtn" value="Search" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could possibly explain the error a little better, and possibly point me in the right direction. I'm confused as to why it is saying the resultset is closed when I'm using a different one altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not using a different one altogether:

```
id = Integer.toString(r.getInt("PlantID"));
html += r.getString("EnglishName") + "-" + r.getString("ScientificName")
```

That `r` refers to the previously-closed `ResultSet`, not the new `sqr`.

Note that giving the new result set a new name isn't really necessary except for readability, but you remove that advantage by giving them generic, useless names anyway.

Comment: i missed that completely, although it still throws up the same error. and i didn't know that about ResultSet

Comment: @user3119946 That it's a `ResultSet` is immaterial; a reference is a reference. I don't believe you'd get a result set closed exception on a result set that isn't closed, though.

Comment: ok thanks anyway, is my solution a good way of approaching the problem? or would you go about it differently?

Comment: ok yes im an absolute idiot took another look at my code this morning there was one part that was still using r.getString...thanks for the help