# JSP Multiple SQL Selects

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I am getting familiar with Java through involvement on a servlet web service project that is now up and running.  But the stakeholders want a front end that will allow them to examine the audit table set up in a SQL server database.  I am trying to quickly put one together in JSP with initial success but now stuck.

I want a drop down list to provide a list of all the users (Unique).  I have acheived this using a JSTL taglib method following the link below with the following SQL;

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(USER_ID) FROM AUDIT_MESSAGE".
```

http://www.apekshit.com/t/205/JSTL-SQL-Query-Tag-Example

Now I want, when the user clicks on one of the users names it automatically populates another drop down list with a list of times that user logged in with the following SQL;

```
SELECT SESSION_ID, EventTIME FROM dbo.AUDIT_MESSAGE
WHERE OPERATION = 'loginResponse' AND RESULTS = 'OK'
AND USER_ID = 'firstdropdownlistselection'
```

Then when an item from the second drop down list option is selected a third SQL statement of;

```
Select * FROM dbo.AUDIT_MESSAGE
WHERE SESSION_ID = 'seconddropdownlistselection'
```

This is then used to populate a list box of the Users events at the selected time.

I have found the following link below offering another method but I am unsure whether to continue with the method I have started with or is there a better way.  Can someone please advise me on what method would work best?

[Multiple ResultSets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687249/multiple-resultsets)

Thanks in advance

AJF

Answer (score 0):

You could display the whole database table information(minus the ids) if this is what they want.

If you want to do it in these steps (select user, select session, display information) what you are doing is correct.

Comment: What I want is to have the two drop down boxes act as two filters. First one filters to select the relevant user, second one filters to show the relevant users login times and then the list box shows the events that user performed during that particular login. As I mentioned I have managed to apply the first dropdown list box using the JSTL taglib method but how would I next proceed? Thanks in advance